# Tools for painting a wall

Tags: paint

I had a dry wall job done and I need to paint the wall. A touch up might work as well but I bet i will not end up with a finished result.

Can you list the set of tools needed for doing the painting efficiently?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the texture of the wall, I'd try with **just a 2-3 inch brush**, one coat of primer, then two coat of the same exact paint as the rest of the wall. Ideally some leftover from the original painting.

Needless to say, let dry between coats and clean/dry your brush thoroughly. 
Edit: For cleaning the brush, run water over it until the water runs completely clear, then run some more water. Personally, I use a regular fork to comb the brush as I rinse.

You'll remove the hanger while you paint, right?

Comment: I was not planning to remove it? can i cover it with tape?

Comment: Also, i was thinking that its a better idea to paint the entire wall and not do touchup

Comment: If you plan on doing the entire wall, you'll also want a roller and a pan. But if you go with a roller, to do a better job, then you have to remove the hanger. Otherwise the roller will leave a not totally uniform coat/finish as you go around the hanger. And if you do the entire wall, you'll have to make the trims with the brush and use masking tape.

Comment: okay. Thanks. Is a bucket better than a pan?